# How to find by _Id in mongoDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to find in my DB with `_id`.it works with others like  'name...' 
but with _id, I get a syntax error.
For example, this is my DB.find input.

```
{ "_id": ObjectID("584820a96866b6283361a4b9")}
```

I get a syntax error: **ObjectId is not defined.**
I also tried these codes:

```
{ "_id": 'ObjectID("584820a96866b6283361a4b9")'}
{ "_id": '584820a96866b6283361a4b9'}
{ "_id": 584820a96866b6283361a4b9}
```

But none of them working.

What's my problem?

Comment: try ObjectId instead of ObjectID

Comment: you can find [`ObjectID`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) in the [`mongodb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mongoose

```
// Using Node.js `require()`
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Using ES6 imports
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("584820a96866b6283361a4b9")})
```

If you are using mongoDB

```
// Using Node.js `require()`
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
// or var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId if node version < 6 

// Using ES6 imports
import { ObjectId} from 'mongodb';

find({_id: ObjectId("584820a96866b6283361a4b9")})
```